# Quickly find circles from an array after clicking on Canvas

Tags: algorithm, 2d

I have an array of circles on my canvas. They are randomly located. I want to find the circle after clicking on the canvas very fast. I don't want to go thought all array and compare coords of each circle and cursor coord. I don't want to sort the array by X-coord or Y-coord and realize quick or binary search. Is there any exist algorith to simplify my request od finding hitted circle?

Comment: How many circles do you have? (scale is enough, dozens? hundreds? millions?...?) How many times this op is expected to take place? How often is the list of circles updated? Is it guaranteed there is no overlapping, and at most one circle needs to be found?

Comment: If you were to consider x and y coords for sorting (thing you said "no") you could divide the canvas on a grid by a certain "tile size" and add the circles to the 3D arrays they touch (perform normal hittest on startup). On click you get the position of the cursor, divide by the "tile size" and round down to get 3D array indexes and only run the hittest in those circles. A circle would be in grid[x][y][i], and you would have to keep both 1D and 3D arrays in synch (maybe create your own object to manage those). Won't post as answer 'cause you said "I don't want to sort by x and y".

Comment: @amit, not many, several.. about 2 or 3 dozen. Op is pretty hard by time. More of this I need to calculate hitting right in the circle. But fortunately it's not difficult. But I ask you to tell me if there is any exsisting algorithm to my case?

Comment: @SparK, I did something you've said some time ago... And I see what you are talking about.... Thx!

Comment: @nightin_gale If you have only few circles, I fail to understand why not search all of them, is it a performance bottleneck? (according to a profiler?) If not, this is a premature optimization, and will most likely be un-noticeable, just go with the simple linear search solution.

Comment: So you want a particular result, but you don't want to have to go through the steps required to get that result? Sounds like you should be looking for some help with magic skillz, not with programming...

Comment: gyes, you understand me wrong. I am lookng for existing algorithm. I represent you a particular case of mine. If my boss give me another task with 1 thousend circle and greatly hard and difficult operations on each of one, what should I do? I realize extra unnesessary premature optimization in my case. I've already done sorting and bisearch, but I asked for existing optimal algorithm. Thx for your patient and attention)

Comment: And what about overlappping?

Comment: I haven't solved this problem yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) which lets you store two-dimensional coordinates very efficiently. Since you are running in the browser, I'd recommend the d3.js implementation, which even comes with a very nice [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214).

Comment: I think this is the very method I've been looking for!!! I found a solution with R-tree 2 years ago, but I had doubt for using tree. Now I'm gonna sink deeper with it! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using a PM quad tree spatial data structure.  A PM Quadtree recursively partitions the euclidean n space where each sub tree is an origin with 4 children on the plane, 8 children in 3 space, etc. As a technical note, the quadtree is the case of the plane when the root has 4 children, the 3 space is called an oct-tree, etc.

Typically for a 2d plane, the dimensions are written as all points (0,0) to (2^k, 2^k) for k in Z (the set of integers).  That way the partitions are "nice" in the sense that each origin is divisible by 2.

The idea is that no two points or polygons can lay in the same quadrant.  If there is more than one point in the quadrant, then you must keep recursively partitioning until the point or polygon can be placed, all by itself in a quadrant, that is, until you reach the minimum 1x1 bucket that holds one point.  The root is typically the largest origin, which has four children.  Each child is a quadrant in the plane, so that the first child is Quadrant I, second child quadrant II, etc.

If you store your circles in the pm quad tree, then you can quickly find the nearest circle by starting at the quadrant associated with the selected point p.  once you have located the quadrant of the selected point, then you look for the first ancestor that is a circle.

This nearest neighbor algorithm can run no worse than the height of the pm-quad tree, which is log base 4 of (2^k * 2^k) = log base 4 of (4^k) = O ( k ) where k was our "nice" upper bound.

They are also fun to implement.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: Even getting down to a 1x1 quad won't guarantee that at most 1 circle intersects with it.  Better to make the leaf nodes hold lists/arrays of circles, and stop subdividing once either some minimum size (e.g. 1x1) is reached *or* a small-enough list of circles remains (which can then be tested in brute-force fashion).  Also be specific about what you mean by "in" -- you (should!) mean "if any part of the shape intersects the quad".